# Get current index with LESS Recursion

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to make this:

[image: Worry Level]

I have an array like this:

```
@levels:'level_one','level_two','level_three','level_four','level_five','level_six','level_seven','level_eight';
```

Each of those levels also has a corresponding variable which is a colour, and match a class in the list markup of the level indicator. 
I'm able to loop through these easily enough to generate out the background colours for each level.

I want to be able to have the heights automatically set for each item, so theoretically if I wanted to add a 9th or 10th level to the indicator, I just add the colour variable, add it to the array and add the relevant markup, without having to explicitly set the height on each class.

```
.for(@levels); .-each(@color) {
   @name: e(@color);
   &.@{name} {
      background:@@name;
   }
}
```

I'm looping through the levels like the above, but it is somehow possible to get the current index of the loop as well as the count of the @levels array to work out a percentage based height for each item? Eg. if there's 10 items, the first item is 10% in height etc etc.?

Looking forward to any suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using [`for.less`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) snippet: There's additional `@i` variable available in the `.-each` scope (the variable is implicitly inherited from `.-each`'s caller).

So you can write this as (with unnecessary quotes removed):

```less
@levels:
    level_one,
    level_two,
    level_three,
    level_four,
    level_five,
    level_six,
    level_seven,
    level_eight;

.for(@levels); .-each(@name) {
    &.@{name} {
        background: @@name;
        height: (100% * @i / length(@levels));
    }
}
```

## - - -

In Modern Less you'll achieve the same using the [Lists](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists#less-plugin-lists) plugin where the `.for-each` statement has explicitly specified index variable:

```less
@levels:
    level_one,
    level_two,
    level_three,
    level_four,
    level_five,
    level_six,
    level_seven,
    level_eight;

.for-each(@name, @i in @levels) {
    &.@{name} {
        background: @@name;
        height: @i * 100% / length(@levels);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was considering adding an explicit `@index` (and maybe other) parameter to `.each` itself but did not yet invent a good non-bloating way to make it optional :(

Comment: I didn't see about the @i variable. That's perfect and works a treat. Thanks!!